# Is this twisted cube like graph planar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

[image]

I couldn't find any planar representation of this graph neither could I find a subdivision or minor of $K_{5}$ or $K_{3,3}$. So I don't know how to go about it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you contract the two long vertical edges, you are left with $K_{3,3}$
So $K_{3,3}$ is a minor of your graph, which is in turn not planar.

[image]

Comment: Great solution!